# Handle Event and define parameter after event parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, ecmascript-6, frontend

```
let testTime = document.querySelectorAll(".testTime"); // this List has 3 value. 30, 60, 120
testTime.forEach((x) => {
    console.log(x.innerHTML);
    addEventListener("click", selectTime(this, x));
});

function selectTime(e, item) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
}
```

I want to define a parameter, after `e` parameter and `e.preventDefault()` for the function `selectTime`.

And I want to use `item` in `selectTime`

```
testTime.forEach((x) => {
    console.log(x.innerHTML);
    addEventListener("click", selectTime(this, x));
});
```

I use `this` keyword but It gave me an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function
    at selectTime (time.js:20:7)
    at time.js:13:31
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at time.js:11:10
```

Comment: This looks like it may be for a list of items where you select an option? Could a checkbox or radio button be closer to your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic and syntax is all wrong. You don't callthe event listener to anything in your `forEach` loop and you are calling `selectTime` the wrong way in the `addEventListener` function. `addEventListener` must be always called on some DOM element, and as the second argument you pass it a callback function which will be called after the click is fired. When you pass a callback function, you just pass the function definition, without parentheses. What you're doing now is calling the function. This is how the code should be properly structured

```
let testTime = document.querySelectorAll(".testTime");
testTime.forEach((time) => {
    console.log(time.innerHTML);
    time.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        selectTime(event, time)
    });
});

function selectTime(e, item) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
}
```

Comment: you can just `time.addEventListener("click",  selectTime);` the `item` will be available as the `event.currentTarget`. So `function selectTime(e){e.preventDefault(); const item = e.currentTarget; ...}`. Even better use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation#:~:text=Attach%20an%20event%20listener%20to,occurs%20on%20a%20child%20element.)